# Playing video on fullscreen mode in QT

Tags: c++, qt, video, cross-platform

I want to play(shared, not multiple) video file(mp4) using **QMediaPlayer**(with output videothread to **QGraphicsVideoItem**) on multiple monitors on the single computer, connected by HDMI/DVI cable.
I made a video playback on a single monitor, but I need to play this video on several monitors as one.
I need of crossplatform(Linux/Windows) solution and i must provide configuration monitors for playing video in my application.
Whether it is possible to organize a means of QT 5.4 or extended C++ libraries? 
If yes, please prompt me the best way to do it.
Sorry for bad English and thanks for the help in advance!

Hello! I need to make playing video overlay images.
I am used QT components QMediaPlayer and QGraphicsVideoItem to organize it.
But I could not stretch the video to fill the screen(fullscreen mode).
It looks like this:
[image: Output video]
Please, help me. Thank you.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QWebView>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QFile>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QtMultimedia>
#include <QGraphicsVideoItem>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    this->centralWidget()->setLayout(layout);

    layout->addWidget(ui->graphicsView);
    ui->graphicsView->setStyleSheet("background: transparent");
    this->showMaximized();
    QMediaPlayer * player = new QMediaPlayer();
    QGraphicsVideoItem *item = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    item->setSize(QSize(ui->graphicsView->width(),ui->graphicsView->height()));
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    player->setVideoOutput(item);
    qDebug() << item;
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(item);
    QPixmap pix1( "/home/ibragim/examples/ntv.png" );
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/ibragim/examples/sm.mp4"));
    player->play();
    ui->graphicsView->show();
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addPixmap(pix1.scaledToHeight(100))->setPos(160,30);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: See `QVideoWidget::setFullScreen()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might do what you desire ...

```
void QGraphicsView::fitInView(const QGraphicsItem * item, Qt::AspectRatioMode aspectRatioMode = Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio)

This is an overloaded function.

Ensures that item fits tightly inside the view, scaling the view according to aspectRatioMode.
```